# Angular route id change, updating reactive form state

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angular-reactive-forms

Say I'm on a route `#/user/1`, and change the route to `#/user/2`. it won't fire `ngOnInit` which is expected, as it's the same component already initialized.

In the current setup, a `resolver` on the `user/{id}` route fetches userdata and then either a property `this.user$` is available on the component, which we then subscribe to, or receive the plain object from an `@Input`; `this.user`.

Then in `ngOnInit` we create a formBuilder:

```
@Input() user: User;

ngOnInit () {
  this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    firstName: [ this.user.firstName ],
    lastName: [ this.user.lastName ]
  });
}
```

What happens here when I change the `id` in the route, the form is not updated.

A solution would be to get the component to re-render somehow (In React you could force this by passing a unique `key` property to the component, to force it to re-render), but I don't know how, especially if the component is directly called by the router.

Currently we have this workaround:

```
user$: Observable<User>;
user: User;

ngOnInit () {
   this.user$.subscribe((user: User) => {
     this.user = user;
     this.initUserForm();
   });
}

initUserForm () {
   this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [ this.user.firstName ],
      lastName: [ this.user.lastName ]
    });
}
```

Which introduces some new issues like:

- If the `user$` Observable gets triggered by a different part of the application, it will override the current form values.
- I have to make sure that any change on the `user$` object is the latest, and I don't want to update it on every key press or change.

I expected the reactive forms to be reactive in that it would update the form whenever the state changes, somehow being one-way bound to the state.

The other workaround (without subscribing) would be to do:

```
@Input() user: User;

ngOnChanges (changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if (changes.user && changes.user.previousValue) {
    if (changes.user.currentValue.id !== changes.user.previousValue.id){
      this.initUserForm();
    }
  }
}

initUserForm () {
   this.userFormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      firstName: [ this.user.firstName ],
      lastName: [ this.user.lastName ]
    });
}
```

Which is even messier than the first, but has less issues with unwanted refreshes.

But something tells me there must be a better way of implementing forms, and switching between `id`s.

If somehow we could trigger the component to re-render that would solve it, or solve it in a neater way on the component and get the reactive form to be truly reactive.

As a sidenote we use ng4 and ngrx4, but we don't want to put every form state change on the store, only after submitting it.

Comment: Have you thought about subscribing to Router events, specifically NavigationEnd?

Comment: @ChauTran Not NavigationEnd specifically, i did try to subscribe to `this.route.params`, but that fires earlier than `user$` changes, so it's still out of sync. I suspect it'll be the same for NavigationEnd. I also tried doing 
 `zip` but they won't fire in sync with the right `id`.

Comment: Actually, the NavigationEnd should mean the resolver is done... I'll give it a try.

Comment: Did it work ???

Comment: @ChauTran Yes, that solved the syncing issue of the `route.params` being ahead. So while this solves my issue I wish there was a better way, like `key`ing the route to force it to re-render.

Comment: Me too man. What I am doing to minimize the potential issues of memory leak is: `this.routerSub = this.router.events.filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(...)` then I `unsub` the `routerSub` on Destroy.

Comment: @ChauTran I've actually now discovered the `RouteReuseStrategy`, which I think might be a better approach to forcing a components to re-render on route/id change. It's still not ideal, but it avoids having this hacky approach.